# How delete record?

Tags: lightning-web-components

when you try to delete an entry from the table, an error message appears

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)  
   public static void deleteContact(String contactId) {  
    String query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact where Id = ' + contactId;
     Contact contact = Database.query(query); 
      if (contact != null){
         DELETE contact;
      }
   }
```

js code

```
deleteRecord(event){
      contactId = event.target.dataset.recordid;
     deleteContact({contactId: this.contactId});

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding a console.log(contactId); before calling the apex method from javascript so you can make sure there is not an issue there. Also, providing the whole js file would help us make something you did not notice

Comment: Have you imported `deleteContact` in JS? can you add more code? or minimum viable code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: You can't cache a delete operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error message says, `contactId` is not defined - rather not correctly referenced

```
deleteRecord(event){
     contactId = event.target.dataset.recordid;
     deleteContact({contactId: this.contactId});
}
```

This has problem as `this.contactId` will refer to class variables. But you need to refer to the `contactId` inside `deleteRecord` method. So, correct method is :

```
deleteRecord(event){
     contactId = event.target.dataset.recordid;
     deleteContact({contactId: contactId});
}
```

**Note:**

1. You can even use `deleteContact({contactId});`. (according to `ES6` - object literals)
2. Remove `Cacheable=true` in apex method annotation as that is only for reading data and not DML operations.

Comment: changed, the same mistake